Codomain of holomorphic chart
I am beginning to study complex manifolds and have come across the following possible issue when extending from the real to the complex case.
Beginning from the real case, we can define a real (smooth) manifold to be a second countable Hausdorff space $M$ together with a smooth atlas. The elements of the atlas are ordered pairs $(U, \phi)$, where $U \subseteq M$ is open, and we can either force the chart map $\phi$ to be a homeomorphism from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ OR simply a topological embedding from $U$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$ whose image is open. In either case, we then go on to say the chart maps are smoothly compatible one with another.
So, a definition for a complex manifold is a second countable Hausdorff space that has a holomorphic atlas. Now we have ordered pairs $(U,\phi)$ where $U\subseteq M$ is open and $\phi : U \to \mathbb{C}^m$ is the chart map, and the charts are holomorphically compatible. Every source I've seen defines the chart maps $\phi$ to be an embedding from $U$ into $\mathbb{C}^m$ whose image is open. But can we recover the other method? Is it alright to force the holomorphic charts to be homeomorphisms from $U$ onto $\mathbb{C}^m$?
There isn't any issue for the Riemann surfaces $\mathbb{C}$ and $S^2$. In the former case, the atlas is just $\{(\mathbb{C},\text{id}_{\mathbb{C}})\}$, whereas in the latter case we use stereographic projection relative to the North and South poles. My worry is that my definition attempt breaks down for the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$. If $U \subseteq \mathbb{D}$ is open and $\phi : U\to \mathbb{C}$ were a bijection and a holomorphic chart map in the sense that it lives in a holomorphic atlas, then wouldn't $\phi^{-1} : \mathbb{C} \to U$ be a holomorphic map in the sense of single-variable complex analysis? If so, then Liouville's Theorem should say $\phi^{-1}$ is constant, which contradicts its bijectivity.
Is there a way to salvage my definition for holomorphic charts? Or are we really forced to define holomorphic chart maps to output in an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^m$?

No, there is no way to save it. You will get a class of complex manifolds with your definition which is quite boring, namely, disjoint union of countably many copies of $\mathbb C^n$.

@MoisheKohan This is not true, for instance, one gets all $\mathbb{C}P^n$'s. You might not be able to get any other interesting manifolds, but the fact that it works for some nontrivial ones implies this is an interesting question.

@J.V.Gaiter: Right, also (partial) flag-manifolds for complex semisimple Lie groups.
